# Assert an Element is NOT present python Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am using selenium python and looking for a way to assert that an element is not present, something like:

```
assert not driver.find_element_by_xpath("locator").text== "Element Text"
```

Comment: What's wrong with that line of code?

Comment: @BlackBear Well, won't that take a long time depending on what the timeout is?

Comment: It fails, saying: Unable to locate element

Answer (score 5):

You can use below:

```
assert not len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("locator"))
```

This should pass assertion if none of elements that match your `locator` were found or `AssertionError` if at least 1 found

Note, that if element is generated dynamically by some `JavaScript` it could appear in `DOM` **after** assertion executed. In this case you might implement [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) :

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "locator")))
    not_found = False
except:
    not_found = True

assert not_found
```

In this case we'll get `AssertionError` if element appeared in DOM within 10 seconds

Answer (score 4):

assuming you are using py.test for your check in `assert` and you want to verify the message of an expected exception:

```
import pytest

def test_foo():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
        x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("locator").text
    assert excinfo.value.message == 'Unable to locate element'
```

Answer (score 3):

To assert that an element is ***not*** present you can use either of the following approaches:

- Using `assert` and [*invisibility_of_element_located(locator)*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located) which will assert that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.

  ```
  assert WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_Element_Text_element")))
  ```
- Using `assert not` and [*visibility_of_element_located(locator)*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) which will assert that an element is not present on the DOM of a page and not visible.

  ```
  assert not WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_Element_Text_element")))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check that an element does not exist, the easiest way to do that is using a with statement.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def test_element_does_not_exist(self):
    with self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException):
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("locator")
```