# How to check if an element is not displayed in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

How could I check to see if an element is not displayed. I would think it looks something like this.

```
if(element.is_not_displayed):
    doSomething()
else
    doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: Not present: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142054/assert-an-element-is-not-present-python-selenium, not displayed (but present): https://www.browserstack.com/guide/isdisplayed-method-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

To start with, there is no `is_not_displayed` attribute in [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491).

To simulate a similar logic, instead of an *`if-else`* loop you may use a *`try-except{}`* loop inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `invisibility_of_element()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
try:        
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element(element))
    doSomething()
except TimeoutException:
    doSomethingElse()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `until_not` as shown bellow

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, "time you want to wait".until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"someID")))
```

**Example:**

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"transpdiv-0"))) #here yout wait to the element appear

WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"transpdiv-0"))) #here you wait the element disappear
```

**Note:** you have to add the same imports like undetect Selenium says:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```